# function's apply method in javascript confused me

Tags: javascript, firefox

I assumed that #apply was defined in Function.prototype,I override it with code as below:

```
Function.prototype.apply = undefined;
```

Then, I test it with FireBug!

```
var a1 = [];
var a2 = [3];
console.log(a1.push.apply); // output: undefined
console.log(a2.push.apply); // output: apply()
console.log(typeof a1.push.apply); // output: "undefined"
console.log(typeof a2.push.apply); // output: "function"
```

How could it be that, it really confused me! If there is another #apply coexist?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can't reproduce this on my Chrome and Palemoon (lightly modified Firefox)......

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Opera, too. What version of FF are you using?

Comment: Can you test whether `a1.push === a2.push` and `a1.push.apply === a2.push.apply` before you undefined it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in FF 14/Win 7

Comment: You don't have to assume, read [ECMA-262 sec 15.3.4.3](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.3).

Comment: Everything get normal today when I test with the same code, I do not know why it produced that confused result yesterday! Thank you all. I test it with Firebug 1.10.2 in Firefox 14.0.1